# How to remove the border around the anchor?

Tags: html, css

When I go to a anchor (ID) I get a border around the section. How can I remove this border?

[this is the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irra1.png)

Comment: Please, post your code instead of image(HTML, CSS, Jquery, Jsfiddle and etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the same by just writing

```
{ outline: none; }
```

in your css

Answer (score 0):

to remove border you can use `border: none;` in css.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 outline:none;
}
```

This is based on browser. Chrome gave the border instead of Firefox so if you are using Chrome then u have to write this code in your CSS file.